# How to write this math term?

Tags: math-mode

I have the following sequence definition:

[image]

I can't find a way to write this in Latex. Any hints where to start?

Comment: just use `cases` environment. search `cases` first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since the other `cases` questions ask some specific questions about it, here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
g(n) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3}n & \text{wenn } n \equiv 0 \mod 3,\\
\frac{4}{3}n + \frac{1}{3} & \text{wenn } n \equiv 1 \mod 3,\\
\frac{4}{3}n - \frac{1}{3} & \text{wenn } n \equiv 2 \mod 3.
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

The [`mathmode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) documentation is extremely helpful for answering these sorts of questions. You can find it on your system using `texdoc` or its equivalent.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  g(n) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{2}{3} n &\ text{wenn } n \equiv 0 \mod 3 \\
    \frac{4}{3} n - \frac{1}{3} & \text{ wenn } n \equiv 1 \mod 3 \\
    \frac{4}{3} n + \frac{1}{3} & \text{ wenn } n \equiv 2 \mod 3
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \def\arraystretch{1.3}%
  g(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{llll}
    \frac{2}{3} n & \text{wenn} & n \equiv 0 & \mod 3 \\
    \frac{4}{3} n - \frac{1}{3} & \text{wenn} & n \equiv 1 & \mod 3 \\
    \frac{4}{3} n + \frac{1}{3} & \text{wenn} & n \equiv 2 & \mod 3
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `cases` environment from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is defined as `\left\{\def\arraystretch{1.2}\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}} ... \end{array}\right.`.